# Reversing to django admin index page

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to redirect django index url to admin url which I can do something like below:

```
# url.py

path("", admin.site.urls,),
url("^admin/", admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
```

However, this generating warning

```
WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'admin' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
```

Hence, I decided to create a index view and use `django.view.genertic.redirectview` to pass to Django admin root URL as url attribute. I am trying find better way to generate Django admin root url using `reverse` function.

Comment: The error warns you that there are two urls hitting the same view, remove `url("^admin/", admin.site.urls, name="admin"),`  and go to your localhost:8000 it will go to the admin itself

Answer (score 3):

Ahh, found it. might help to someone.

```
reverse('admin:index', current_app=self.name)
```